# How to make rspec see a method which is there, but probably it's class would need an instance?

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec

I'm having a problem using rspec while testing a method inside a class. This class is inside 2 modules and I find putting it in *class << self* unnecessary. Since the stuff I'm doing is a kind of plugin I really don't want to create an instance of this class. This method doesn't really depend on anything

```
it "Returns 2 elements" do
    Something::Anotherthing::MyClass.get_data("data").length.should == 2
end
```

That's an example and what I get is:

```
NoMethodError:
undefined method `get_data'
```

I might be making a newbie's mistake here since I'm really new to rspec and quite new to Ruby. I guess it should work as soon as I have an instance of MyClass or I put get_data into self section. Is there any way to avoid it (this method depends on 1 class var which is static [is that a correct word in Ruby?]).

Comment: Why would you want to avoid creating an instance when testing an instance method?! If it's not something that needs to be an instance method, make it a class method.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm really new to all of this and I'm sorry for my complete lack of basic concepts of design. After some thinking I've come to realize there is no reason for that method to be an instance method. Guess it was a design flaw at my code rather than lack of options at rspec.

Comment: It wouldn't have been a lack of options in rspec, either, testing an instance method naturally requires an instance-which rspec can do automatically anyway.